# How to change membership type parameters to effect a revised end date

Tags: civimember

I'm working with an organisation which is changing their membership cycle. Originally the membership type was fixed and annual and we had a start date of April 1. Consequently the vast bulk of the members have a membership end date of March 31.

The organisation now wants to move to a calendar year cycle, still fixed, but with a start date of Jan 1.

I made the change to the membership type, and it appears to be working as expected for new membership sign-ups. Renewing members on the other hand still seem to be getting renewed through to March 31 of the following year, indicating that the renewal process is looking only at the duration and not the start date.

This is creating confusion, as although we are telling members of the change in the membership cycle, they are still getting receipts that show their new end date as March 31 as opposed to December 31.

I can't see how I could alter the membership type so that renewing members get renewed through to December 31.

What's the correct approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm not too sure about this @Graham, memberships is not entirely my field of expertise. Is this a case of a change at one date (as I suspect) or does the data need to change over the year? If it is a one time change you might try in a test environment to change the data in the civicrm_membership table and see if that works?

Comment: If I understand you correctly it is just a change at one date. What data should I be looking to change?

Comment: @Graham I would try to change the column end_date in the civicrm_membership table. But perhaps it is wise to try on a local install first (at least that is what I would do :-)) So set the value to '20141231' if that is what you need.

Comment: I'll give it a try, however I'm surprised that this is not something that is controllable via the UI. I think this is probably not an uncommon requirement.

Comment: I agree @Graham. This is either new or I do not know the UI way. Sometimes knowing the database and being able to manipulate minimizes endurance in looking in the UI :-)